# Pushing function value to array within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a function which returns a value within an ng-repeat.  It basically creates a total for each object of the ng-repeat.

How do i push each return value to a new array?  I have tried the following:

```
 $scope.lineTotal = function(line){
    var markup = 1 + (line.markupPct / 100);
    var discount = 1 - (line.discountPct / 100);

    var lineTotal = line.price * discount * markup * line.qty;

    return lineTotal;

    $scope.newArray.push(lineTotal);
}
```

Comment: The last line is not executed because there is a return which ends the execution of the function

Comment: You need to switch the lines `return lineTotal;` and  `$scope.newArray.push(lineTotal);`

Comment: This is very similar to last question you asked. This function does not tell us a thing about your data array which is what you need to work with to get totals. Please provide relevant data model details. Pushing to array won't help without another function that reduces that array

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.lineTotal = function(line){
    var markup = 1 + (line.markupPct / 100);
    var discount = 1 - (line.discountPct / 100);

    var lineTotal = line.price * discount * markup * line.qty;

    $scope.newArray.push(lineTotal);
    return lineTotal;
}
```